# How to open a PWA using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: reactjs, keyboard-shortcuts, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am creating a PWA with Reactjs. Once the app is installed, is it possible to open it on pc/mac using a shortcut? Something like [getcommande.com](https://getcommande.com/), but using a PWA.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any PWA-specific way to do this, but you can just do it however you'd configure a keyboard shortcut to run any application. I don't know about Mac, but on Windows I've done either

1. put the PWA in the taskbar. If it's in, say, the 5th position, then you can launch it by pressing windows key + 5.
2. Right-click the PWA, select Properties (or Show More Options first on Windows 11) then click Shortcut key and press the combination you want to use. It seems like you can't use the Windows key this way, though.

Comment: (2) opens a new instance of the PWA. doesn't switch to existing instance if it already exists. so if you want a custom shortcut you will need to use autohotkey to remap the win+5 key specified in (1).